# How to use toString method to print two objects within a third object?

Tags: java

I'm having problems with an assignment where my understanding of java objects is flawed. I have created 3 classes. One that creates an object to hold values making up a full name, The second class is a MailingAddress class that extends the FullName class and utilizes inheritance through the super() method. The third class is a shipping label class where it requires 2 MailingAddress objects... one object denoted as shipTo and another as shipFrom, with a single method printLabel(). All objects override the toString() method for output, Below is my code and output:

```
public class FullName {

    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    FullName(){
        title = "";
        firstName = "";
        middleName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }
    FullName(String title, String first, String middle, String last){
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = first;
        this.middleName = middle;
        this.lastName = last;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return title + ". " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    }
}// end of class
```

```
public class MailingAddress extends FullName{

    private String streetAddress, city, province, postal;
    private FullName fn = new FullName();

    MailingAddress(){
        super("","","","");
        streetAddress = "";
        city = "";
        province = "";
        postal = "";
    }

    MailingAddress(String title, String first, String middle, String last, String street, String city, String prov, String postal){
        super(title, first, middle, last);
        this.streetAddress = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.province = prov;
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return fn.toString() + " " + streetAddress + "\n" + city + ", " + province + "\n" + postal;
    }
}// end of class
```

```
public class ShippingLabel extends MailingAddress{
    private MailingAddress shipTo;
    private MailingAddress shipFrom;

    private ShippingLabel(MailingAddress shTo, MailingAddress shipFm){
        this.shipTo = shTo;
        this.shipFrom = shipFm;
    }
    private void printLabel(){
        ShippingLabel label = new ShippingLabel(shipTo, shipFrom);
        System.out.println(label.toString());
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Ship to:" + shipTo + "\n" + "\n" + "Ship From: " + shipFrom;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MailingAddress shTo = new MailingAddress("Mr","Jonathan","Daniel", "O'Connor","109732","Edmonton", "Alberta", "T5m1K3");
        MailingAddress shipFm = new MailingAddress("Mr","Piercy","Michael","Miller","23 Oreville way","Calgary","Alberta","C3p5o1");
        ShippingLabel sL = new ShippingLabel(shTo,shipFm);
        sL.printLabel();
    } // end of main
}// end of class
```

output:

Ship to:.
 109732
Edmonton, Alberta
T5m1K3

Ship From: .
23 Oreville way
Calgary, Alberta
C3p5o1

Process finished with exit code 0

What I don't understand is why the values utilizing the FullName constructor aren't printed in the output. I expect the toString method in classes FullName and MailingAddress to collaborate making up the ShippingLabel. Hopefully by looking at my code you can see what my thought process is, and explain where it is flawed.

Comment: MailingAddress HAS-A FullName not IS-A FullName, unless there is functionality extension you should never inherit classes .. remember [composition over inheritance](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `MailingAddress.toString()` function.

You are not using correct object to call `toString()` function. Since `MailingAddress` is inherited from `FullName` so you don't need to create a new member of type `FullName`. You should use inherited `toString()` of `FullName` using `super`keyword.

Following is corrected version. See [the complete code working here](https://ideone.com/jK0hGX):

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " " + streetAddress + "\n" + city + ", " + 
                 province + "\n" + postal;
}
```

[**Note:** Relationship between `MailingAddress` and `FullName` is `has-a` and not `is a` i.e. *`MailingAddress` has a `FullName`* but *`MailingAddress` is not a `FullName`*. Above solution is using `is-a` relationship. See here the [solution using `has-a` relationship](https://ideone.com/UE2Xvg). ]

Comment: Thank you for the insight, makes total sense and produces the desired result. Please let me know if there is any redundancy or a more favorable way of coding the anticipated output. As a student my knowledge is limited to course content, when my ambition is practicality and industry standard, as I really enjoy learning the Java language.

Comment: @J.OC Regarding, *Please let me know if there is any redundancy or a more favorable way of coding the anticipated output.* You can ask for inputs on your code on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).